# Cómo quitar STOPWORDS de una columna de un csv usando Pandas? Python

Tags: python, csv, nlp, nltk

Quisiera saber cómo puedo quitar *stopwords* a la `columna b` de un `csv` usando Pandas. La `columna b` a utilizar a sido convertida en array.

**Precódigo:**

```py
# importar NLTK y crear un set de stop_words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords # to get rid of StopWords 
nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words = set(stop_words)

# Leyendo el archivo
df = pd.read_csv(root_new_fn)

# Separando las columnas
(x_train, y_train) = (df.columna_b, df.columna_a)

# Convirtiéndolo en arrays
train_data_arr = np.array(list(x_train)) # Columna para aplicar stopwords
train_labels_arr = np.array(list(y_train))
```

**OUTPUT ESPERADO:**

Parecido a esto, sin embargo usando la librería pandas:

```
import csv
with open(root_new_fn, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        article = (row[1])
        for word in stop_words:
            token = ' ' + word + ' '
            article = article.replace(token, ' ')
            article = article.replace(' ', ' ')
        x.append(article)
        train_data_arr = np.array(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `pandas.Dataframe.apply()`

```
def stop_words_replace(article):
    for word in stop_words:
        token = ' ' + word + ' '
        article = article.replace(token, ' ')
    return article

df.columna_b = df.columna_b.apply(lambda article: stop_words_replace(article))
```

Comment: al final lo que hice fue `df['columna_b'] = df['columna_b'].apply(
    lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in stop_words])
    )
` me pareció una buena opción y más sintética.