# Hacer un replace exacto Python pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-3.7, str-replace

estoy haciendo el siguiente código donde quiero eliminar palabras de parada (stopword), pero cuando elimino por ejemplo la palabra `al` se me elimina también sobre grupos de texto que no quiero que suceda, por ejemplo `VALVE INOP` queda como `VVE INOP`. Actualmente este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re


df = pd.read_csv('/Users/jorgepontigo/text_mining_reliability/raw data/faults_systems.csv', header=0, sep=',',parse_dates = ['failure_date'], usecols=[0,1,2,3], dayfirst = True)

df["fault_name_clean"] = df.fault_name.str.replace("AL", ' ', regex=False)\
        .str.replace("A", "")\
        .str.replace("IN ", "")\
        .str.replace("THE ", "")\
        .str.replace("DISPLAYED ", "")\
        .str.replace("DAILY ", "")\
        .str.replace("FAULT ", "")\
        .str.replace(" CHECK ", "")\
        .str.replace(" PROBLEM ", "")\
        .str.replace(" POSITION ", "")\
        .str.replace(" REPORTA ", "")


print(df["fault_name_clean"])
```

Alguien me puede ayudar? por ejemplo en el segundo replace solo elimine las coincidencias exactas de `A` ya que si ven lo que imprime el código en la prima fila, desaparecen todas las `A`.

Agradecería montones su ayuda. Les adjunto el input CSV que uso en el código.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pKQQ9zP4cdLCSmEO5ZuylmEX1hYsWP0i/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar expresiones regulares

```
import re 
cadena = "VALVE INOP"

print(re.sub(r"\bAL\b", " ", cadena)) #Output: VALVE INOP

print(cadena.replace("AL",'')) #Output: VVE INOP
```

Aquí tienes una buena guía: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

**EDIT:**

Para utilizar una expresión regular dinámica lo que puedes hacer es pasarla a una cadena, es decir:

```
import re
cadena = "VALVE INOP"
input = "A" #Lo pongo así por simplicidad
rx = r"\b"+input+"L\b"
print(re.sub(rx, " ", cadena)) #Output: VALVE INOP
```

Comment: Genial pero pero tengo una duda, lo estoy haciendo para la serie de pandas así: `df["fault_name_clean"] = re.sub(r"\bAL\b", " ", df["fault_name"])` pero me genera este error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Prueba con `df["fault_name_clean"] = re.sub(r"\bAL\b", " ", str(df["fault_name"]))`

Comment: buena al final lo hice así igual `df["fault_name_clean"] = df.fault_name.str.replace(r"\bA\b", ' ', regex=True)`

Comment: Vale @Gonzalo-GC , tengo una última duda si yo definirera antes un input, por ejemplo `input=AL` y eso lo ingreso al código me genera error, se podrá hacer? quedaría así: `re.sub(r"\b"input"L\b", " ", cadena)`

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Si el objetivo es remover todas las stopwords de tu texto (evitando hacer replace una a una), puedes usar las stopwords de nltk.

Una posible adaptación de tu código sería algo como esto:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
#import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/jorgepontigo/text_mining_reliability/raw `data/faults_systems.csv', header=0, sep=',',parse_dates = ['failure_date'], usecols=[0,1,2,3], dayfirst = True)`

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

EDICION: Corrijo el codigo y añado una mejora pasando todo el texto a minúscula antes de remover stopwords. Este código lo he verificado con tus datos:

```
df['words'] = df["fault_name"].str.lower().str.split()
print (df['words'])# Aquí tendrás texto separado en palabras y en minúscila

df['fault_name_clean']=df['words'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop_words])

print(df["fault_name_clean"])# aquí tendrás las palabras sin stopwords

print(df["fault_name_clean"])
```

Si quieres saber cuáles palabras se consideran stopwords (y se eliminarían de tu texto) puedes verlas haciendo:

```
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Puedes encontrar ejemplos similares removiendo stopwords con nltk en:
[Cómo quitar STOPWORDS de una columna de un csv usando Pandas? Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333463/c%C3%B3mo-quitar-stopwords-de-una-columna-de-un-csv-usando-pandas-python) y 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523254/python-remove-stop-words-from-pandas-dataframe.

Comment: Vale gracias cuando realizo esta línea `df['texto_tokenizado'] = df['Tu_columna_de_texto'].apply(stop_words)` que en mi caso sería así `df['texto_tokenizado'] = df['fault_name'].apply(stop_words)` tengo este error `'set' object is not callable`

Comment: @Jorge Ponti, he hecho una edición de la posible solución para verificar que ejecuta  sin errores. También he pasado a minúscula el texto antes de omitir stopwords, para mejorar los resultados.